# Obtaining date a set distance away from a given date

Tags: r, date

How can I obtain the date that is a set number of periods later/earlier than a given date? Eg if `x <- as.Date("2001-01-01")`, how do I get a date which is 6 months later (`2001-07-01`) or earlier (`2000-07-01`) than `x`? Complicating factors include the day of month of the initial date, or the number of days per month.

Comment: Please only ask one question per question.

Comment: @Joshua, he is only asking one question..

Comment: @Griffin: I commented and the OP edited within 5 minutes of their initial posting time, so their edit doesn't appear... a rather annoying SO "feature" if you ask me.

Answer (score 3):

```
library(lubridate)
ymd("2001-01-01") + months(6)
ymd("2001-01-01") - months(6)
```

Comment: Ah, well this makes more sense than my suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

```
seq( as.Date("2001/01/01"), by = "6 months", length = 2)[2]
# [1] "2001-07-01"
```